# Is it possible to run a multigroup SEM with mediation?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

It's easy to create mediation in lavaan using SEM.
It's also easy to run an SEM multigroup model by using a grouping variable.
BUT: is it possible to run both in the same model?
When I try, I get coefficients for each group, as expected, but my defined mediation parameters are printed only for the 2nd group (indirect and total effects, proportion). How do I get that printed for both groups?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, and although it was a very silly error on my part, I will post my answer here, just in case it may be helpful to someone else.

In lavaan to use modifiers for multiple groups one needs to use a vector, for example, `c(value_group1, value_group2)*var1`.
I had equality constraints on some coefficients across two groups, so some variables were defined as `c(z, z)*var1`. So, when I defined coefficients for mediation, I used the same labels for both groups, without realizing that that automatically constrained values across two groups. I had something like this: `c(Mediator1pathA1, Mediator1pathA1)*Var1`.
Then I defined parameters, such as: `indirect_M1 := Mediator1pathA1*Mediator1pathB1`.
As lavaan interpreted these labels to be the same across the two groups, it printed only one set of defined parameters (so, I only had 1 value for `indirect_M1` printed after the last group, instead of `indirect_M1_Group 1` and `indirect_M1_Group2`.
I realized that to have two sets of parameters calculated, I'd have to assign different labels in each group). So, instead of `c(Mediator1pathA1, Mediator1pathA1)*Var1` I assigned them as `c(Mediator1group1pathA1, Mediator1group2pathA1)*Var1`.
Then I defined indirect effect parameters as I have described above, for two groups, and voala! - I got my two sets of defined parameters for two groups.